# How to open an activity on click of a DrawerLayout navigationView item in android?

Tags: android

What function should i use to open an activity when a  DrawerLayout navigationView item is clicked, and do i need to make object for that activity?

Here is my code so far:

```
public boolean onNavigationItemSelected(MenuItem item) {
    // Handle navigation view item clicks here.
    int id = item.getItemId();
    if (id == R.id.nav_profile) {
        // Handle the camera action
    } else if (id == R.id.nav_cv) {

    } else if (id == R.id.nav_subscription) {

    } else if (id == R.id.nav_logout) {
}
```

Answer (score 0):

You can open activity like this.

Intent I=new Intent(MainActivity.this,actvitytoopen.class);
StartActivity(I);

Answer (score 0):

You better use fragments instead of activities and change them using FragmentManager. You can find plenty of tutorials just by searching on Google/Youtube.

Answer (score 0):

You can start new activity by

```
Intent intent = new Intent(this,NextActivity.class);
intent.putExtra(EXTRA_MESSAGE, message);
startActivity(intent);
```

for further info refer https://developer.android.com/training/basics/firstapp/starting-activity.html

Answer (score 0):

I spent a lot of time trying to call a new activity by clicking on navigation drawer item . but it is virtually impossible and if it is possible in any other way I tried, then it is sure that on the called activity there will be no drawer navigation drawer then. Fragment is a part of similar activity so calling fragment is the correct way. If you are calling fragment, navigation drawer will still be there on the side pane and you would be able to select between different items of the drawer.